# Why do I get square brackets when trying to convert array to JSON string using stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, stringify, square-bracket

When I try to convert the array below to a string using JSON.stringify, I get to see empty square brackets only. I tried console.log to debug, but I do see the data I want to convert into a string, so what am I doing wrong here? Any help will be much appreciated!

```
function jsonSuccess( data ){

        var jsonArr = new Array();

        for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
            var shipInfo = new Array();
            var shipRows = new Array();

            $.each( data[i], function( key, value ){


                if ( key == "EniNumber" ) {
                    shipInfo['E'] = value;
                    //console.log( shipInfo.E );
                }

                if ( key == "Name" ) {
                    shipInfo['N'] = value;
                }

                if ( key == "StartDate" ) {
                    shipInfo['S'] = value;
                }

                if ( key == "Rows" ) {

                    $.each( value, function( subKey, subValue ){

                        var rowContent = {
                            "T": subValue.T,
                            "X": subValue.X,
                            "Y": subValue.Y,
                            "D": subValue.D
                        }

                        shipRows.push( rowContent );

                    });

                    shipInfo['R'] = shipRows;
                }

            });


            jsonArr[i] = shipInfo;

            var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonArr);
            console.log(myJsonString);
        }

    }
```

Comment: `shipInfo` is not an array, it is an object so try `var shipInfo = {};`

Comment: Your array doesn't have any values, instead it has properties. Therefore, `[]` is the expected console value when you log it. It will also have a length of 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using an Array as an object.

In Javascript you have Arrays and objects. But as you may know Arrays are also objects and this has some weird implications.

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = "foo"; // this is fine
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // [ "foo" ]
arr.length; // 1 ok
```

But since an Array is an object, we can also assign properties:

```
arr.foo = "bar";
console.log(arr); // [ 0: "foo", foo: "bar" ]
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // [ "foo" ] .. where did bar go?
arr.length; // 1 huh?
```

We're mixing array values and object properties.

The JSON encoder looks at the object and sees that it's an (instanceof) `Array` and serializes it. It looks at `arr.length` (which is 1 in the example) so you get just `[ "foo" ]`. The properties on the array are ignored.

---

It's important to realize the difference between array valus and object properties. **Arrays in JavaScript are *never* associative**. If you set a property on an Array it wont increase the length and it wont show up if you loop over it in a for-loop.

---

Change:

```
var shipInfo = new Array();
```

To:

```
var shipInfo = {};
```

Comment: I get a slightly different output from your second code snippet. `[foo: "bar"]`, `[]`, and 0 rather than 1. but i suspect a lot of that is just differing browsers interpreting it differently in the console. Still a good explanation though. I use chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm not used to javascript, but I sure am glad to see people helping me right after I post. :D

Answer (score 2):

`shipInfo` is not an array, it is an object so try `var shipInfo = {};`

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Mkrwc/1/), [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Mkrwc/)